# Bug in GWT Canvas drawing filled polygons

Tags: canvas, gwt, polygon

I draw two polygons and a filled rect. The polygons are expected to be light grey, the rect is red. But the second polygon is also red which should not be the case. Ist this a bug in GWT? If yes, how can I report a GWT bug?
Here is the source code:

```
// draw lightgrey polygon, context ist Context2D object:
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.setStrokeStyle(colorGrey);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(1, 1);
context.lineTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(10, 5);
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.closePath();
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.stroke();
context.fill();

// This polygon should be lightgrey but is red:
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.setStrokeStyle(colorGrey);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(20, 20);
context.lineTo(28, 15);
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.closePath();
context.setFillStyle(colorLightGrey);
context.stroke();
context.fill();

// draw red rect:
context.setFillStyle(colorRed);
context.fillRect( 11, 10, 4, 4);
context.fill();

// forced termination here, more would be drawn in this program otherwise:
PlaybackView test = null;
test.getTopFocusPanel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the polygon is re-drawn in red because there is another (unnecessary) fill() after fillRect(), and no new path is started with beginPath().

Comment: Indeed, a beginPath() added helps and removing the last fill() helps,too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FrankEschenbacher, Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please, take a moment  and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section including [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Happy coding! :)